# How do I use an enum for a field?

Tags: java, spring-boot, eclipse, model-view-controller, enums

I am very new to Springboot and would like to create a Basketball team management system using MVC model. In one particular field, for the player positions, I need to make it an enum. How can I use an enum with a field? do I need getters and setters for it? I have no idea how to do it and it's an assignment. Thank you!

Comment: Just like any other field - access modifier, type, name. Getters and setter, no one but you can tell, we don't know how you will use the field.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
public class Player {
    private String name;
    private String number;
    private Color favoriteColor;

    enum Color {
        RED,
        GREEN,
        BLUE
    }
}
```

From there you write code to assign a reference to one of those enum objects into the member field of objects of that class. This works the same for your field of `Color` as for any other kind of object such as a field of `String` or a field of `LocalDate`.

In a real world example the enum should be in a class of its own.

Comment: Good code. But I disagree with the claim that the enum should be defined in its own separate class. If the  enum `Color` only makes sense within the context of a player, than it does indeed belong nested within `Player`.